# How to optimize flask_admin search over strings

Tags: postgresql, flask-admin

I created an index on a text column, but searches using filters (contains) still takes like 15 seconds, and (equals) takes around 4 seconds.

A search in the flask admin search box is similarly slow.

So what would be a way to optimize this search? BTW: I'm talking 9 million strings. Simply searching this in pure python would be a lot faster (when in memory).

Here's the analyze:

```
... text = 'project'

Aggregate  (cost=546598.03..546598.04 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=1742.969..1742.969 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on twitter  (cost=0.00..546597.64 rows=156 width=0) (actual time=1742.966..1742.966 rows=0 loops=1)
         Filter: ((text)::text = 'project'::text)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 9129062
 Planning time: 0.159 ms
 Execution time: 1743.000 ms
(6 rows)

... text ilike '%project%'

 Aggregate  (cost=547376.38..547376.39 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=18154.062..18154.062 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on twitter  (cost=0.00..546635.55 rows=296332 width=0) (actual time=0.177..18101.235 rows=498397 loops=1)
         Filter: ((text)::text ~~* '%project%'::text)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 8631301
 Planning time: 1.142 ms
 Execution time: 18154.104 ms
(6 rows)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `EXPLAIN` `ANALYZE`? if so, show the result, if not, try to see whats going on with the result. Here it is how to use them: [explain/analyze](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/reading-an-explain-analyze-query-plan)

Comment: @Dan I added the results for doing the queries using `psql`.  I'm starting to think that this might be normal behavior?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes)

Comment: also, what type of index are you using? how many indexes does the table has? does the data have the same table space as the indexes? can you show the full query?

Comment: Look [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/datatype-textsearch.html) postgres has couple indexes for text search